# Blank page for a VueJS app on Github pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, github-pages

I have deployed a Vue app on the following [repository](https://github.com/christopherkade/STracker/tree/gh-pages)'s gh-pages branch.

But accessing https://christopherkade.com/STracker gives the following error on Firefox (and similar errors on other browsers):

> Loading failed for the  with source “https://christopherkade.com/static/js/manifest.5f330dcceda3a8431045.js”.
>
> Loading failed for the  with source “https://christopherkade.com/static/js/vendor.d99d5ed4cd2156cc1a6f.js”.
>
> Loading failed for the  with source “https://christopherkade.com/static/js/app.ccc0f9d5d6f02f3b3285.js”.

Please note that I have tried changing `assetsPublicPath` to `'./'` in `config/index.js` and added `<base href="/">` to my `index.html`.

What could be causing such a path issue?

Comment: https://learnvue.co/tutorials/deploy-vue-to-github-pages this really helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to change the index.html file in /dist folder. Removing the / from static. And copy it to docs folder. My github page point to that branch.

I have a "publish" script in package.json to do this automatically

`"publish": "npm run build && rm -rf docs; cp -r dist docs && sed -i -e 's/src=\\//src=/g' docs/index.html ; sed -i -e 's/href=\\//href=/g' docs/index.html"`

An example using the simple webpack template https://github.com/vitogit/vue-chessboard-examples 
Another using the webpack template https://github.com/vitogit/vue-chess-guardian

Comment: But that implies that I'm pointing to the /docs folder and not simply the gh-pages branch, right? I'll try to remove the '/' from the statics and see the result. EDIT: It actually worked ! I'll take part of your script and see what I can do with it, thank you !

Comment: Although I now have the following problem: the url goes to `https://christopherkade.com/login` instead of `https://christopherkade.com/STracker/login`, which means that when I reload the page it takes me back to `https://christopherkade.com`

Comment: I guess something with your router. But not sure if I can help you because I didn't used router on github pages.

Comment: Solved it, I just needed to change my router to redirect to /STracker/login and not /login ! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I similarly got mine working with a bit of trial and error, following the instructions across a number of stackoverflow and github posts, and the vue deployment instructions https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html.  I don’t know if you have to make all of these changes, because I haven’t tried removing any, but this is the full list of changes I found to work.

1. Create a vue.config.js file in the project root and adding the
   publicPath setting with my repo name.  (publicPath: ‘//’)
2. Changing vue router mode from history to hash (mode: 'hash')
3. Removing the path in the config index.js file.  You do this by
   changing assetsPublicPath: '/'   to    assetsPublicPath: ''.  This
   is probably cleaner than doing it manually in the index.html file, as some
   responses suggest.
4. Adding/changing the vue router base in the router
   index.js file (base: ‘//’ )
5. Building the project after all these changes are made
6. Deploying the project.  I didn’t follow the full deploy.sh instructions. However the git commands I used were to add the files (git add –A), commit the files (git commit –m ‘deploy’) and then push the distribution files to the gh-pages branch (git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages). Of course this will add and commit everything whereas the vue instructions are more focussed.
7. Setting the github pages settings to point at gh-pages branch.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to change my `publicPath` in `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/GitHub-Repo-Name/'
  : '/'
}
```

In this case, I would be deploying to `https://username.github.io/GitHub-Repo-Name/`